# Paste contents of range into 1 cell - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to copy the contents of a range starting in cell A2 and then paste the contents in cell E7.

The code that have written out here has been working for me when my ranges were about 100 rows, but when I am trying it with a larger range (200 rows) it is only pasting about 70% of the content.

Is there a way to fix this so it works every time?

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As String
For Each rng In Selection
i = i & rng & " "
Next rng
Range("E7").Value = Trim(i)
```

Comment: How many characters? There is a cell limit, around 32k.

Comment: Or perhaps you have a blank cell in the middle. Use end(xlup).

Comment: Your first comment was exactly right. The text exceeded 32k. The text has a bunch of unbreakable spaces so after I substitute out the unbreakable spaces ((Char(160)) the text  goes down from 32k to under 4k.

Answer (score 0):

Putting those two suggestions together

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As String
For Each rng In range(Range("A2"),Range("A" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup))
    i = i & rng.text & " "
Next rng
if len(i)>32387 then msgbox "Too Long" 'test if too long
Range("E7").Value = Trim(i)
End Sub
```